# run a spark program in dse4.6

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I have written a Java spark program and want to run it under dse4.6 by using the command dse spark-submit.

I understand that I have to start dse in spark analytics mode.But as I understand that spark comes integrated with dse 4.6, so does this mean that when I have to create a jar file from my java program to run it under dse4.6 spark analytics mode, then I have to remove the spark  core jar from my program and then create the jar for my application and  then  run it  in dse.

Though the question may sound silly but I am still wondering that if spark is integrated with DSE then still I should include spark core in my pom.xml as maven dependency or shall I always remove my  spark-core jar in my program before making the jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question. Thanks for asking!

The short answer is:

> To use the helper classes included in `dse.jar` in your application

We recently updated the [DataStax docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html) to include a better example of how to build custom Spark jobs against DSE. You can also check out the program by Ryah Svhila on which this documentation is based. It's on his [github](https://github.com/rssvihla/dse_spark_maven_java_demo) repo.

Comment: Thanks phact.does this mean I need  to remove spark core jar and only include dse.jar

Comment: Thanks Phact.@phact I will run the way you told and confirm you the results.

Comment: but if I remove spark core from my  java progran and keep dse.jar , it has started throwing compilation error for all spark core related keywords like . JavaSparkContext,JavaRDD,  SparkConf etc

Comment: Correction take a look at Ryan's pom.xml https://github.com/rssvihla/dse_spark_maven_java_demo/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: he has included  spark core too apart from dse4.6 

       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>